# My code was rolled back by the CM, the next step?

Tags: svn, version-control

Our Configuration Manager thinks that my last check in broke the build and rolled back bunch of files I had checked in.  After I ether fix it or show that the breakage wasn't caused by me, what is the right way to get my code back into SubVersion?

Do I do an svn update and re-check in the code or something with SVN commands to go back to the version I had originally checked in?

Comment: of course I was able to build locally.  It is a long story why certain aspects are different on my workstation vs the build server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to re-check in the files. You can go back to the revision you had committed by:

$ svn merge --revision HEAD:xxx

where xxx is the revision with your last changes.

Comment: Make sure you have a clean checkout with no edits before you do this.

Comment: That worked.  I just needed to add the working copy directory at the end.